# Lotus Notes Xpage, how to get max api document

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, lotus

I have a db test.nsf. In db have a form fa_user and view v_User.

I add documents of form fa_user (for example: 20 documents).

I use "test.nsf/api/data/collections/name/v_User" to get api document from  fa_User, but it only get 10 document.

How to get MAX?

Answer (score 1):

Use [URL parameters](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Domino+Access+Services+9.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=Viewfolder_entries_GET_dds10&content=apicontent) `count` for number of entries and `start` for starting entry:

```
test.nsf/api/data/collections/name/v_User?start=0&count=20
```

You can get the **total number** of view entries with HTTP Output parameter `Content-Range` (e.g. value "items 0-19/88" indicates the response includes entries 0 through 19 of a total of 88 entries) or with response field `@siblings` (if it's a flat view).

Read entries in chunks for better user experience or if you have more than 1000 entries:

```
...start=0&count=200
...start=200&count=200
...start=400&count=200
```

As Stephan pointed out in his comment, max. 1000 entries can be read at once.

Comment: Thanks, but i need to get all, not 20 (20 only ex)

Comment: There's a hard limit of 1000 documents at a time.

Comment: @stwissel: thanks, good point. Soul: so, if you have more then 1000 documents then get docs in chunks by 1000.

Comment: Thanks everyone so much

Comment: You're welcome. As you are new to StackOverflow: please consider to accept the answer like shown here  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/223607